# Do container queries work on <html dir="rtl">?

Tags: css, container-queries

I have a task to implement which could benefit from container queries, but it seems that when switching to `ar` lang makes container queries not appear. It is not a complicated query basic one:

container.cssm

```
.container{
    container: listingStats / inline-size;

}
```

item.cssm

```
.item-container {
    @container listingStats (max-width: 45rem) {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

It seems to work for `ltr` but not for `rtl`. Stack is React 16 with webpack

Searched on docs and stackoverflow, but did not see anything related to that. Maybe I missed something

Comment: Maybe add a sample that reproduces the issue.